# How to select from another table during SQLLDR importing file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Is there way to create SQLLDR control file such a way it checks ID number before inserting data into another table and if ID does not match, loader throws it into dicard file?

In original import file there is a column: ID which include 8 digit set of numbers.
Then we have a ID table where these 8 digit ID´s found.

Now I need to check from this ID table first, if ID in file match or not. Matched ones will be inserted into table SETS and mismatches ended into sets.dsc -file.

Can I use WHEN or should I put this selection right into ID inside quotation marks?

We use Oracle 11

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you rather create **referential integrity constraint**? If ID doesn't exist in the "ID table" (which is "parent"), then such a row won't be loaded from the input file. Oracle will raise

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated-parent key not found

error.

I mean, why reinvent the wheel?